# Arrays rendered in a SOAP query with PHP

Tags: php, soap

I've created arrays before with PHP/MySQL, but I'm having trouble working on an array that is rendered in a query via SOAP interface from PHP and am hoping someone can help me understand.  My SOAP query uses a function (called get_file_list) to pull down a list of files from a server.  And it works, no issues there.  This is what the query looks like;

```
$data = $soapClient->get_file_list('201401271000','201401271100','id0');
print_r($data);
```

And here's the output;

```
stdClass Object
(
    [FileName] => Array
        (
            [0] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_07_201401271024_392042
            [1] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271021_1480779
            [2] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271010_1480769
            [3] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271038_1480793
            [4] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271020_1480778
            [5] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271014_1480772
            [6] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271035_1480791
            [7] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271046_1480799
            [8] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271019_1480777
            [9] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271018_1480776
            [10] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271007_1480766
            [11] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271047_1480800
            [12] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271045_1480798
            [13] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271024_1480781
            [14] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271051_1480803
            [15] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271034_1480790
            [16] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271054_1480805
            [17] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271028_1480785
            [18] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271025_1480782
            [19] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271026_1480783
            [20] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271030_1480787
            [21] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271027_1480784
            [22] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271049_1480801
            [23] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271012_1480770
            [24] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271050_1480802
            [25] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_01_201401271010_568947
            [26] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271002_1480763
            [27] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_01_201401271100_568951
            [28] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271058_1480807
            [29] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271009_1480768
            [30] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271033_1480789
            [31] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271055_1480806
            [32] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271008_1480767
            [33] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271003_1480764
            [34] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_01_201401271029_568948
            [35] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271040_1480795
            [36] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271016_1480774
            [37] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271036_1480792
            [38] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271000_1480761
            [39] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271039_1480794
            [40] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271041_1480796
            [41] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271044_1480797
            [42] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271001_1480762
            [43] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271015_1480773
            [44] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271031_1480788
            [45] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_01_201401271054_568950
            [46] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_01_201401271030_568949
            [47] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271005_1480765
            [48] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271013_1480771
            [49] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271053_1480804
            [50] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_01_201401271001_568946
            [51] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271017_1480775
            [52] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271022_1480780
            [53] => cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201401271029_1480786
        )

)
```

My goal is to render just the filenames in a table.  I guess where I'm getting stuck is that the examples I'm finding show how to create the array and assign it a variable name;

```
$arrayList = array(array_contents);
```

Then you can run a count on the variable;

```
count($arrayList)
```

Which yields an integer.

Then, just create a for loop;

```
for ($i=0; $i <= count($arrayList); $i++)
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>$arrayList[$i]</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

And this will just keep looping until your i value is less or equal to the integer rendered from the count($arrayList) operation.  My situation seems different because I'm not creating the array.  Is the name of the array "$data" (from the $data = $soapClient->get_file_list('201401271000','201401271100','id0') variable)?  Running count($data) doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $data variable does not hold an array but a php stdClass object that contains an array with the name FileName.

you could do the following:

```
foreach($data->FileName as $name){
    echo '<tr><td>'.$name.'</td></tr>';
}
```

Whitch would loop over the items in your object and print them.

Or if you wanted to follow your guide

```
$arrayList = $data->FileName;
for ($i=0; $i <= count($arrayList); $i++)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$arrayList[$i]</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```